# C# Dictionary get all keys with same value

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a Dictionary with Keys and Values. Is it possible to get all Key who has the same Value?

Example **1=456894, 2=548962, 3=548962, 4=654876** and then get the Key 2 and 3 because it has the same value.

`Dictionary<int, int> doublechek = new Dictionary<int, int>();`

Comment: What if `1=123, 2=123, 3=234, 4=234` ? should it just pick your favourite ?

Comment: What do you want to do if there is several multiple values? Or do you want result for a precise value? Or having the most duplicate value?

Answer (score 8):

One possible approach:

```
var result = doublechek
    .GroupBy(z => z.Value)
    .Where(z => z.Count() > 1)
    .SelectMany(z => z)
    .Select(z => z.Key)
    .ToList();
```

`GroupBy` and `Count` will get only those with duplicates. `SelectMany` and `Key` will get the keys of those with duplicates (i.e. 2 and 3).

Answer (score 1):

I would create a new "flipped" dictionary, containing all the unique values from `doublecheck` as keys, and for each key a list of values containing all the keys from `doublecheck` that have the referenced value.

Like so:

```
Dictionary<int, List<int>> flipped = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();

foreach (var key in doublecheck.Keys)
{
    if (!flipped.ContainsKey(doublecheck[key]))
        flipped.Add(doublecheck[key], new List<int>());

    flipped[doublecheck[key]].Add(key);
}
```

The dictionary `flipped` can be used to find all the keys of `doublecheck` that have the value you are searching.

**Update**
When using `TryGetValue` the code looks like this:

```
Dictionary<int, List<int>> flipped = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();

foreach (var key in doublecheck.Keys)
{
    if (!flipped.TryGetValue(doublecheck[key], out var valueList);
    {
        valueList = new List<int>();
        flipped.Add(doublecheck[key], valueList);
    }

    valueList.Add(key);
}

return true;
```